# Is there in spring-batch (or somewhere else) retryable JobRepository 'out-of-the-box'?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have very simple batch-job implementation using spring-batch.
I have just a one step with one Tasklet there like this:

```
(stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
            runStep(job,chunkContext, parameters);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
```

where runStep - contains just sequential operations. No retries for the step or job.
I'm using standard `SimpleJobRepository` that saves state of jobs into db.

I have next problem - when db is not accessible my jobRepository cannot save job status, job is failing but the state of it stays 'STARTING' or something like this (not FAILED).
I want to add retying for all 'update***' methods in jobRepository.
I've implemented it using aspect that retries only for TransactionException :

```
@Around("execution(void org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository.update*(..))")
    public void retry(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        jobRepoRetryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
            try {
                joinPoint.proceed();
            } catch (TransactionException e) {
                log.error("Retry={}, exception occurred:", retryContext.getRetryCount(), e);
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Retry={}, no next retry for exception occurred:", retryContext.getRetryCount(), e);
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
```

I don't need retry for my step or job (even for tasklet), I just want to have retries for saving state of job into db.

I'm wondering maybe there is some 'standard' mechanism for such functionality in spring-batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there in spring-batch (or somewhere else) retryable JobRepository 'out-of-the-box'?

There is no retryable job repository out of the box. You can do it using AOP as you did or try to extend the default one an add the retry feature programmatically (see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54045145/5019386)